# Server 2003 login screen will not appear

Tags: windows-server-2003, login

One of my servers refuses to let me log in as administrator. The thin Microsoft Sever 2003 appears but login name and password is blank. I can guess where these fgo but when i enter correct admin login and password it goes to a yellow triangle and an exclamation mark. What has happened? If it is a corrupt login profile, can I take the admin login profile file form another server and copy it over? In short- I cannot het on to the server at all ecen though it is running services.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to access the physical console. Is this server configured for remote access? Do you see the same issue if connecting via RDP?

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  I cannot RDP or ping my server.  Thanks for your help!